# Mount network volume from script

Tags: macos, script, network-shares

I have a script that reads data from

```
/Volumes/somenetworkdir/...
```

Each time run it, I have to open Finder and navigate to the relevant network share in order to make OSX mount the volume. Is there a way to get OSX to mount the network volume automatically from a script? Any language is fine, as is a shell command. I guess applescript will be a candidate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `mount` command. It supports several network share formats.

This is for a samba (Windows) share

```
sudo mount -t smbfs -o username=RemoteUser //REMOTEHOST/directory /Volumes/somenetworkdir
```

`man mount` in a terminal will show you the full list of options.

Since this depends on a script, you could include this call prior to accessing that share.

If this is a share you are not always on a network which is permitted to connect to it, have a look at [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/). It will let you run something when on a certain network, so you could mount this share whenever you connect to this shares network.